# how to make MyClass.method(:var) and MyClass(:var) synonymous in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are many gems online that have this behaviour

for example [Fabrication Gem](http://www.fabricationgem.org/#!fabricating-objects) has this behaviour

you can create an object via

```
Fabricate(:person)
Fabricate.create(:person)
```

and the this is the [code](https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication/blob/master/lib/fabrication.rb#L61-L65)
but when I tried to mimic that pattern

```
# app/services/permissions.rb
class Permissions
  def self.call(user)
  # ...
  end
end

def Permissions(user)
  Permissions.call(user)
end
```

but `Permissions(user)` always return error `undefined method 'Permissions' for #<Ability:0x007ff6ea78de88>`

the ability model is

```
# app/models/ability.rb 
class Ability
  # ...
  def initialize(user)
    if user.role == 'Admin'
      # ....
    elsif user.role == 'Manager'
      Permissions(user) # wont work
      Permissions.call(user) # works fine
    end
  end
end
```

the code fine **but when invoked within a rails app it doesn't work**.. so how to make such a behaviour **possible in Rails**?

Comment: is `def MyClass(var)` inside a module or class?

Comment: where are you calling MyClass()?

Comment: unless you're using an old/weird Ruby implementation or there's something else that you're not posting here, your code should work

Comment: Can you show the entire class?

Comment: Add another global method in your permissions file and see if it can be called from the ability model. That way, you can eliminate whether it is a discovery issue or a name conflict. Then, add an instance method to the Permissions class in permissions.rb and see if you can call that from the Ability class. Also, try moving the permissions method to the top ability.rb and see if that fixes it (if that works, and you need this behavior only in the ability class, that shd be a reasonable option).

Comment: @Anand that didn't work... and as @GabrieldeOliveira mentioned in his answer that it's most probably cause the `app/services/permissions` not the "main" ruby object and that it's in a module. but I don't really know how to confirm or deny that

Comment: the code provided in the question works fine **but when invoked within a rails app it doesn't**..

Comment: You cannot invoke a global method in a service file from a model file in rails. I reproed this whole thing in a rails app, and found (as I suggested in my last comment above) that if I move the permissions method to the top of the ability.rb file, it works. Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated yet again based on comments, with a tested workaround: Move the `permissions` method to the top of `ability.rb`, and it should work.

The issue is that rails has a strong convention about what can be accessed from different folders. A global method in a service file is not accessible from a model, something similar to the fact that a view helper is not available in a model.

Comment: the code is in rails project... maybe it something with where the files are defined... the permissions class is defined in `app/services/permissions.rb` as mentioned before

Comment: the code provided in the question works fine **but when invoked within a rails app it doesn't**..

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would replicate it:

```
def MyClass(something)
  "#{something} was created."
end

class MyClass
  class << self
    alias_method :create, :MyClass # MyClass as in Object's private method!
  end
end

MyClass(:rock)        #=> "rock was created."
MyClass.create(:gem)  #=> "gem was created."
```

EDIT: I can't comment yet because my account is new, but if I'm not mistaken your `Permissions` method is being defined within another class/module. What you want to do is to make the `Permissions` method definition in the `main` Ruby object, that is, outside of all classes or modules.

Comment: When you're in IRB and you define a method (without using class or module), you're defining methods in the main object.
You just need to make sure you're outside of any class/module definitions and simply write "def MyClass...", etc.
All methods in Ruby are held by a class, or a module, and when it isn't apparent, by the main object.

Comment: I meant in a rails project... the service is defined in `app/services/permissions.rb`

Comment: Could we have a look at the source file of permissions.rb?

Comment: yeah it's in the question :D

Comment: If that's the whole file then that's very strange. A method like `Permissions` should be available to all classes, including `Ability`, given that it's being defined as a private Object method.
The only thing I can think of is, are these files being loaded in the correct order?

Comment: The `Permissions.call(user)` works fine it's the `Permissions(user)` that doesn't work... And i don't understand what does "private object method" means ..

Comment: the code provided in the question works fine **but when invoked within a rails app it doesn't**..